# Can we make facebook application that allows our users to make new facebook application inside our app?

Tags: facebook

We would like to know,Is it possible to develop  a Facebook application that allows our Applications user to make Facebook Apps through our Website or Through our Application?

Have you guys any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no methods to create fb applications at runtime in an automated fashion.

If I'm not mistaken, they used to have something like that for creating "child applications" but I can't find any referenced for that.

What you can do is ask your users to put in the app id of a fb app they created themselves.

---

## Edit

I managed to find some referenced to the **OLD** way of achieving your goal, it has been deprecated a long time ago though and there are no new alternatives for this.
As for now, you simply can not do it.

Reference:
[Facebook Lets You Easily Integrate into Sites and Widgets with New Create Application API](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/10/15/facebook-lets-you-easily-integrate-into-sites-and-widgets-with-new-create-application-api/) which was found on this thread: [Create a facebook application programmatically](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6264080/create-a-facebook-application-programmatically).

You can find many other threads here regarding this issue. But I can assure you, you won't stumble upon something that will say anything different.

Comment: Any Idea about Child Application?